# Exclude tax price for wholesale customer

Tags: customer, price, tax, customer-group, vat

I am running B2B and B2C website. My problem is that I want to show price with exclude tax for only wholesale customer and price with including tax to retail customer.

How can I achieve? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a simplest, best approach for you that may not require any customisation but this is with some assumptions that I detail below:

1. If you currently have a B2B website and a B2C website under the same system, then it is possible to set up each price display differently for each site (this is in Stores/Configuration/Sales/Tax)

   - now, your B2C customers would need to go to the B2C website
   - you B2B customers would either know to go to the B2B website or would be redirected to it when they log in (this may need a customisation but can be minor)
2. if both your websites are under one same frontend website, then you may have to customise the price rendering. The advice is to change the templates and therefore be less intrusive. This will be a proper job and therefore I allow myself to be superficial just to give you directions, please find 2 prices templates that you can start your modifications onto:

   - `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml, vendor/magento/module-tax/view/base/templates/pricing/adjustment.phtml`
   - If you setup the prices display to show both including and excluding tax, your aim will be to add logic with customer group to either show including or excluding price. Please be prepared to test your site as there are many templates you need to check against and hopefully the first solution may be what your situation is..